# sending fileds and Array to action in asp.net mvc with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to send fields and array to action controller with ajax in asp.net mvc?
when i want to send parameters to action controller my ajax method dont work but i dont solve this problem.
why my ajax method doesnt execute?

> this is my action controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SavePerson(string name, string family, string fatherName, string placeOfBirth,
            string gender, string nationalCode, int personTitleId, bool isBimanaMember,string bimanaDesc,string description,
            SocialNetwork[] social, Phone[] phone, Email[] email, Address[] address, Site[] site, PersonExpertise[] personExpertise, PersonHonor[] personHonor)
        {
            //...some code
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

> and this is my script this code try to send parameters (field and array)to action controller with ajax

```
$("#save").click(function () {
var socialArr = [];
socialArr.length = 0;
//socialnetwork array
$.each($("#socialNetworkDataTable tbody tr"), function () {
    socialArr.push({
        Url: $("#url", this).val(),
        SocialNetworkTypeId: $("#SocialNetworkTypeId", this).val(),
        Description: $("#description", this).val()
    });
});

//phone array
var phoneArr = [];`enter code here`
phoneArr.length = 0;
$.each($("#phoneDataTable tbody tr"), function () {
    phoneArr.push({
        Number: $("#number", this).val(),
        PhoneTypeId: $("#PhoneTypeId", this).val(),
        Description: $("#description", this).val()
    });
});

//email array
var emailArr = [];
emailArr.length = 0;
$.each($("#emailDataTable tbody tr"), function () {
    emailArr.push({
        Name: $("#name", this).val(),
        Description: $("#description", this).val()
    });
});

//address array
var addressArr = [];
addressArr.length = 0;
$.each($("#addressDataTable tbody tr"), function () {
    addressArr.push({
        CountryId: $("#CountryId", this).val(),
        StateId: $("#StateId", this).val(),
        CityId: $("#CityId", this).val(),
        PostalCode: $("#postalCode", this).val(),
        PostalBox: $("#postalBox", this).val(),
        AddressText: $("#addressText", this).val()
    });
});

//site array
var siteArr = [];
siteArr.length = 0;
$.each($("#siteDataTable tbody tr"), function () {
    siteArr.push({
        Url: $("#url", this).val(),
        Description: $("#description", this).val(),
        IsPure: $("#isPure", this).val()
    });
});

//personExpertise array
var personExpertiseArr = [];
personExpertiseArr.length = 0;
$.each($("#personExpertiseDataTable tbody tr"), function () {
    personExpertiseArr.push({
        Name: $("#name", this).val(),
        Description: $("#description", this).val()
    });
});

//personHonor array
var personHonorArr = [];
personHonorArr.length = 0;
$.each($("#personHonorDataTable tbody tr"), function () {
    personHonorArr.push({
        HonorText: $("#honorText", this).val(),
        Description: $("#description", this).val()
    });
});

if (socialArr[0].Url == "")
    socialArr = null;
if (phoneArr[0].Number == "")
    phoneArr = null;
if (emailArr[0].Name == "")
    emailArr = null;
if (addressArr[0].CountryId == 0)
    addressArr = null;
if (siteArr[0].Url == "")
    siteArr = null;
if (personExpertiseArr[0].Name == "")
    personExpertiseArr = null;
if (personHonorArr[0].HonorText == "")
    personHonorArr = null;

var data = JSON.stringify({

    name: $("#Name").val(),
    family: $("#Family").val(),
    fatherName: $("#FatherName").val(),
    placeOfBirth: $("#PlaceOfBirth").val(),
    gender: $("#Gender").val(),
    nationalCode: $("#NationalCode").val(),
    personTitleId: $("#PersonTitleId").val(),
    isBimanaMember: $("#IsBimanaMember").val(),
    bimanaDesc: $("#BimanaDesc").val(),
    description: $("#Description").val(),
    social: socialArr,
    phone: phoneArr,
    email: emailArr,
    address: addressArr,
    site: siteArr,
    personExpertise: personExpertiseArr,
    personHonor: personHonorArr
});

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/People/SavePerson",
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        Console.log(result);
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function () {
        Console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

});

> PROBLEM:why my ajax method dont send parameters to action controller for Saving to db?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: remove datatype and content type and check again. Even after doing this you still not able to accomplish your goal than leave everything.... create model of this objects, then try to perform for ajax.beginform

Comment: Check your browser console for any client side errors and also check network tab to see if the request has been sent..

Comment: I dont have any error just ajax method done execute